# VS Code opening remote SSH window within WSL on host SSH Windows devices?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, openssh

Remote machine is WSL1 on Win10, with SSH configured for Win10 but not WSL. We can access WSL via SSH remotely on terminal by running `wsl`, and we can open VS Code remote SSH windows on any Win10 dir, but we can't figure out how to make VS Code open a WSL dir.

We initially sought to enable remote SSH on WSL1 but this was complicated and we found all complexity / risk could be avoided by simply running `wsl`. Is there a simple way around this for VS Code that doesn't require hosting SSH connections on WSL1?